# pop up at if condition in views.py in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show a pop-up instead of the httpresponse shown as below in views.py after satisfying the if condition - (below is section of code in views.py)

```
if data['check_in'] > now and data['check_out'] > now and data['check_out'] > data['check_in']:
            #Check if the room is available
            if available_rooms is not None:
                if len(available_rooms) >= int(num_rooms_req):
                    for i in num_rooms_req_lst:
                        #Book the First available room
                        # print(available_rooms[i-1])
                        booking = book_room(request, available_rooms[i-1],data['check_in'],data['check_out'],total_cost)
                    return HttpResponse(booking)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Only 1 rooms available in this category')                                                    
            else:
                return HttpResponse('All the rooms of this category are booked! Try another category!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('checkin/checkout date in past or checkout date is prior to checkin date!')
```

so in the above views.py code section - what would be the best way to show the return HttpResponse pop-ups or alerts (but alerts would take me to different html) - I don't want to navigate away from the parent html...

Comment: Do you want pop-up in rendering your page or you just want to send it as an API? please clear your question so that I can help you. Additional info you can told me that's also helps.

Comment: @Omayer Hasan Marif -- thanks for your reply

I need a pop-up from the html which I am calling in the get section of the above code snippet which I've shared i.e. - room_detail_view.html

not sure if I understand about the API...

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import messages

if data['check_in'] > now and data['check_out'] > now and data['check_out'] > data['check_in']:
   if the room is available
      if available_rooms is not None:
         if len(available_rooms) >= int(num_rooms_req):
            for i in num_rooms_req_lst:
                booking = book_room(request, available_rooms[i-1],data['check_in'],data['check_out'],total_cost)
            return HttpResponse(booking)
         else:
            messages.warning(request,'Only 1 rooms available in this category')
            return redirect('rediect_path') #/user/login/                                                    
      else:
         messages.warning(request,'All the rooms of this category are booked! Try another category!')
         return redirect('rediect_path') #add your rediect path
   else:
      messages.success(request,'checkin/checkout date in past or checkout date is prior to checkin date!')
      return redirect('rediect_path')
```

add this in your HTML

```
{% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

We can add these 5 types of messages.

**debug,info,success,warning,error.**

```
messages.debug(request, 'Total records updated {0}'.format(count))
messages.info(request, 'Improve your profile today!')
messages.success(request, 'Your password was updated successfully!')
messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
messages.error(request, 'An unexpected error occured.')
```

**[Please use this for reference](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html)**

Answer (score 0):

@Akash Nagtilak - thanks a lot of answering
I tried using the above but not sure of the couple of stuff -

1. in the rediect_path what can be given because in my code snippet which I posted, its the post section of the views.py which I have added but in the get section I have the html with the context which I want to remain on - for your reference I am pasting the complete class of views.py
2. where should I add the portion which you've given in HTML -

```
class RoomDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id', None)
        form = AvailabilityForm()
        print(form)
        human_format_room_category = get_room_category_human_format(id)        
        if human_format_room_category is not None:
            context={
                'room_category': human_format_room_category,
                'form': form,
            }
            return render(request,'room_detail_view.html', context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('category does not exist')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        #Get room category from kwargs
        id = self.kwargs.get('id', None)

        #Pass request.POST to AvailabilityForm        
        form = AvailabilityForm(request.POST)
        
        #Checking form Validity
        if form.is_valid(): #check the validity of the form and return the cleaned data from the form
            data =  form.cleaned_data
        
        now = timezone.now()
        num_rooms_req = request.POST.get('Num_Rooms')
        print("no rooms requested",num_rooms_req)
        num_rooms_req_lst = list(range(1, int(num_rooms_req)+1))
        #Get Available Rooms
        available_rooms = get_available_rooms(id, data['check_in'],data['check_out'])
        # print("rooms_available",len(available_rooms))
        #get the total charge for the room
        total_cost = find_total_room_charge(data['check_in'],data['check_out'],id)
        if data['check_in'] > now and data['check_out'] > now and data['check_out'] > data['check_in']:
            #Check if the room is available
            if available_rooms is not None:
                if len(available_rooms) >= int(num_rooms_req):
                    for i in num_rooms_req_lst:
                        #Book the First available room
                        # print(available_rooms[i-1])
                        booking = book_room(request, available_rooms[i-1],data['check_in'],data['check_out'],total_cost)
                    return HttpResponse(booking)
                else:
                    messages.warning(request,'Only 1 rooms available in this category')
                    return HttpResponse('redirect_path')                                                       
            else:
                return HttpResponse('All the rooms of this category are booked! Try another category!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('checkin/checkout date in past or checkout date is prior to checkin date!')
```

@Omayer Hasan Marif -- thanks for your reply

I need a pop-up from the html which I am calling in the get section of the above code snippet which I've shared i.e. - room_detail_view.html

not sure if I understand about the API...